# curl: how to not overwrite existing file?

Tags: curl, wget, download

Given a +350MB file online [ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/georeferenced_tiff/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip)

Within a script, the following `curl` command is currently used for downloading :

```
curl  -o ../data/ETOPO1/ETOPO1.zip \
  'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/georeferenced_tiff/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip'
```

Given the target size and downloading time (~20min), I want to download it the first time only. Then, when I restart the whole script, the command should notice the file as already there, and **NOT** redownloading it.

Also, when the output `-o` already exist, **how to NOT restart the download/overwrite the file** ?

Note: preference for `curl`, but other utilities welcome (`wget`, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the command-line option `-C <offset>`:

> Continue/Resume a previous file transfer at the given offset. (...) Use "-C -" to tell curl to automatically find out where/how to resume the transfer. It then uses the given output/input files to figure that out.

([Documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html))

In your exact case:

```
curl \
  -o ../data/ETOPO1/ETOPO1.zip \
  -C - \
  'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/georeferenced_tiff/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip'
```

Comment: Could you exactly rewrite the command. I get an error msg.
`$curl  -o -C ../data/ETOPO1/ETOPO1.zip 'http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/data/ice_surface/grid_registered/georeferenced_tiff/ETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.zip'`
Console error: `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '..'
PK`�>�f����9�vETOPO1_Ice_g_geotiff.tifUT ��M��Mux
                                                           ���;V����}'I�$I�$I�$I�$I�$I�$I�$I�$�$���$�$����L�Lfff�I�I*�$���\{���ys^|����s��r�6��h�smu����\m��m�φ���K�?=�$�o7�0�?s����wJ?�����m�L��.......`

Comment: All right, edited to add a full example.

Comment: Working and validated ! +... Thank you !

Comment: Doesn't work for me, appends some bytes on every repetition.